# How to prove $H_{2i}(X,A), i\in\mathbb{Z}$ is also a generalized homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

We have known that $H_{i}(X,A), i\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a generalized homology and satisfying Eilenberg's Axioms. However, although $H_{2i}(X,A), i\in\mathbb{Z}$ is also a generalized homology, but I met some trouble when I tried to prove it has long exact sequence $$\cdots\xrightarrow{\partial}H_{2n}(A)\xrightarrow{i_*}H_{2n}(X)\xrightarrow{j_*}H_{2n}(X,A)\xrightarrow{\partial}H_{2(n-1)}(A)\to\cdots$$ from the long exact sequence $$\cdots\xrightarrow{\partial}H_{n}(A)\xrightarrow{i_*}H_{n}(X)\xrightarrow{j_*}H_{n}(X,A)\xrightarrow{\partial}H_{n-1}(A)\to\cdots$$ immediately (especially at the connection morphism $\partial\colon H_{2n}(X,A)\to H_{2(n-1)}(A)$).

Comment: Where did you find this claim?

Comment: You should replace "cohomology" by "homology".

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: (I mean examples to verify that you actually get a long exact sequence.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this works: Assume that you have a connecting homomorphism $\partial \colon H_{2n}(X,A) \to H_{2(n-1)}(A)$. Then for $(X,A) = (S^3,S^2)$ and $n=2$ a fragment of the long exact sequence would look like
$$
\cdots \to H_4(S^3,S^2) \stackrel{\partial}{\to} H_2(S^2) \stackrel{i_*}{\to} H_2(S^3) \to \cdots
$$
However, we know from the generalized homology theory $H_*(-,-)$ that you started with, that $H_4(S^3,S^2) \cong 0$, $H_2(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2(S^3) \cong 0$, thus giving an exact sequence $\cdots \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0 \to \cdots$, but this sequence cannot be exact, giving a contradiction. I hope this helps!